# Isekai manga where the main character is transported into a comic

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

The main character is transported into his favorite comic as a third-rate villain and he has to make sure to gain the author's favor to survive.

He meets a gunslinger-type character who is one of the comic's protagonist's sidekicks at a villains headquarters in the first chapter/s, along with the main character of that novel

Comment: You could improve this question by looking at the check lists in [this thread](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question), then editing it to include any further details that come to mind. The more info you can provide, the better the chances that someone will be able to ID this for you.

Comment: I actually read this before but cannot figure out the name of it, sorry.
I read it off some websites, not the main website I usually read my mangas.

But I can give more details:

- Like what they said, It's not really gaining the author's favour but gaining recognition from the author.

- The MC has to do things that can impact the comic/story for him to be in the next chapter of the comic.

- MC meets a loli-girl that tricks him to rob a bank together, they buy invisibility potions and rob the bank after the heist she tricks him and puts rocks in his split of the money and runs away

Answer (score 2):

I managed to find it after a while. It's *[Surviving in an Action Manhwa](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/surviving-in-an-action-manhwa)* by Jinot and Gyeongho KIM.

[image: Front cover of Surviving in an Action Manhwa]

> After a disagreement with the author, Lee Hee-ro transmigrated to the world of his favourite shounen manga, Adventure King! But what’s this, characters have to work hard for their survival? If you’re a two-bit villain, you get defeated by the protagonist from the get-go? If you’re the strongest on the current map, you get hammered down by a newcomer to show off their strength? If you aren’t popular with the fanbase, your character gets deleted?! In a world of endless fights, a crazy sprint to survive just the next chapter begins!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You could improve your answer by giving some details about this, like a plot summary, date of publication, link to reviews, etc.  You might want to read [answer].